# $\sigma$-Algebra generated by a simple characteristic function

Tags: measure-theory, characteristic-functions

Suppose that $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $A \in \mathcal{B}$ be a Borel set.

Suppose that $X = \sum_i a_i\chi_{A_i}$ is a simple random variable defined on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. Show that $A_i \in \sigma(X)$.

Comment: More is needed. For instance it could be that $X$ is a constant function here so that $\sigma(X)=\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$. For that we do not need $A_i\in\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$ for every $i$. Nowhere it is said that $i\neq j\implies a_i\neq a_j$, so....take $X=\chi_A+\chi_B$ where $\{A,B\}$ is a partition of $\Omega$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
\sigma(X) & = X^{-1}(\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})) \\
 & = \sigma(\{A_1,A_2,...,A_n\})
\end{split}
\end{equation}$$

Hence, $A_i \in \sigma(X)$

Comment: Could you elaborate on the second equality please? How to prove that e.g. $A_1=X^{-1}(B)$ for some Borel-measurable  $B\subseteq\mathbb R$?